# Cannot build App IOS Xamarin due to nugget.build restore

Tags: c#, ios, macos, xamarin, nuget

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmhgW.png)Using Visual Studio Mac and developing an iOS App, every now and then, when building the app or even rebuilding i get this error message:

Error: NuGet packages need to be restored before building. NuGet MSBuild targets are missing and are needed for building. The NuGet MSBuild targets are generated when the NuGet packages are restored. (PlatformSpecificBits.NuGet)

I have already installed and installed nuget.build package, i have Nuget package restore automatically, but still i can't build the app.

Anyone as already experienced this or knows the reason why it is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to delete that nuget package and install again , probably it will fix the issue

Comment: What sort of projects are you building? That message is displayed when you are building a .NET Core project and the generated nuget files in the obj directory are missing: `obj/projectname.nuget.g.props` and `obj/projectname.nuget.g.targets`.

Comment: It's a xamarion iOS c# basic project. i have already not only uninstalled nugget but also visual studio and it remains the same....